Proving that $A \subseteq B$ iff $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$
I'm proving the following statement in Daniel Velleman's How to Prove It (p. 133):

Prove that $A \subseteq B$ iff $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$.

My proof
Assume $\mathcal{P}(A) \nsubseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, i.e. assume $\exists C \in \mathcal{P}(A): C \notin \mathcal{P}(B)$. This means $\exists C \subseteq A : C \nsubseteq B$, i.e. $\exists x \in A : x \notin B$. But this contradicts the assumption that $A \subseteq B$. Hence $\forall C(C \in \mathcal{P}(A) \implies C \in \mathcal{P}(B))$, i.e. $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$.
Conversely, we have that $A \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, which implies that $A \in \mathcal{P}(B)$ since $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$. Hence $A \subseteq B$.
Since $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ if $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq B$ if $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, $A \subseteq B$ iff $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$. $\square$
Is there a way to prove the first direction of the equivalence directly instead of resorting to contradiction?

Yes. Every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Suppose $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$.
It is known $\cup_{x\in\mathcal{P}(A)}(x)=A$ and $\cup_{x\in\mathcal{P}(B)}(x)=B$. Since $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$, $\cup_{x\in\mathcal{P}(A)}(x)\subseteq\cup_{x\in\mathcal{P}(B)}(x)$ which means $A\subseteq B$.
Suppose $A\subseteq B$. If $x\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ then $x\subseteq A\subseteq B$ so $x\in\mathcal{P}(B)$. This shows $\mathcal{P}(A)\subseteq\mathcal{P}(B)$.

Let us prove the implication $(\Rightarrow)$ first.
If $X\in\wp(A)$, this means that $X\subseteq A\subseteq B$. Hence we conclude that $X\subseteq B$, which implies $X\in\wp(B)$.
Let us prove the converse implication $(\Leftarrow)$ now.
Since $A\in\wp(A)\subseteq\wp(B)$, this means that $A\in\wp(B)$. In other words, $A\subseteq B$, and we are done.
Hopefully this helps!

Thanks, it does!

Yes.  Assume $X \in \mathcal P(A)$ is an arbitrary element of the power set.  Then by definition of power set, $X \subseteq A$.  We also know that $A \subseteq B$, which means $X \subseteq B$.  (Every element of $X$ is necessarily in $A$, and every element of $A$ is necessarily in $B$, so every element of $X$ is necessarily in $B$.)
Since $X \subseteq B$, by definition of power set we also have $X \in \mathcal P(B)$. But we have now proved that an arbitrary element of $\mathcal P(A)$ is also in $\mathcal P(B)$, which means $\mathcal P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$.

Thank you. I think my difficulty was in spelling out rigorously the fact that every subset of $A$ is a subset of $B$. It is quite straightforward TBH, I could have just done it in terms of the elements of each set.
